# R functions counting elements

Tags: r

I would like to print the element number of the list that is going through a function. For example if there are 10 elements in the list, I would like a counter that will go from 0-10 as the function goes through each element.

```
a = length(url)
    func0 = function(url){
      a  = a-1
print(a)
    }
    cc = lapply(url, func0)
```

However this does not work. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function changes the internal copy of variable `a`, and prints number 9 10 times. To change this behaviour to desired you should change the assignment operator `=` (btw, why not `<-`? equal sign is usually used in definitions of functions' parameters) to the global assignment operator `<<-`.

```
func0 = function(url){
  a <<- a-1
  print(a)
}
```

It will work, but the common recommendation is to avoid the global assignment operator in your code.

As an alternative I can suggest to check the package `pbapply`, which adds progress bar to the `*apply` functions.

```
require(pbapply)
pblapply(url, func1)
```

Where `func1` will stand for the the function you want to apply to each element of the list.